# Manipulating complex lists in Erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have this list in Erlang

```
[{title,
"ad"},
{description,
"fdf"},
{allow_change_subj,
true},
{allow_query_users,
true},
{allow_private_messages,
true},
{allow_private_messages_from_visitors,
anyone},
{allow_visitor_status,
true},
{allow_visitor_nickchange,
true},
{public,
true},
{public_list,
true},
{persistent,
true},
{moderated,
true},
{members_by_default,
true},
{members_only,
false},
{allow_user_invites,
true},
{password_protected,
false},
{captcha_protected,
false},
{password,
[]},
{anonymous,
true},
{logging,
false},
{max_users,
200},
{allow_voice_requests,
true},
{voice_request_min_interval,
1800},
[{captcha_whitelist, []}, 
{affiliations, [{{"test1", "serverdomain.com", []},{owner,[]}}]}, {{"testuser4_gmail.com", "serverdomain.com", []},    {member, []}}],
{subject,
[]},
{subject_author,
[]}]]
```

I am trying to fetch usernames (test1, testuser4_gmail.com) which are under key 'affiliations', but having problem in fetching them from this list.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update :**

I was fine to get 'affilations' key and everything under it but problem in what I am looking for. I am providing an example

```
 ->   Listt = [{captcha_whitelist, []}, {affiliations, [{{"test1", "54.69.16.10", []},{owner,[]}}]}].
    
  ->  lists:keyfind('affiliations',1, Listt).
  Output : {affiliations,[{{"test1","54.69.16.10",[]},{owner,[]}}]}
```

**Target :** fetch values like "test1" and more if available there like "test1", "testuser4_gmail.com"

Comment: Maybe you should show the code of your first tries ?

Comment: I reached to get affiliations but not getting how to move forward. I am providing it as an update in question.

Comment: What's the problem? Output looks correct

Comment: seems like you haven't read question but just update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code example, here are some way how you can extract further.

Here is your code example structure:

```
1> Listt = [{captcha_whitelist, []}, {affiliations, [{{"test1", "54.69.16.10", []},{owner,[]}}]}].
[{captcha_whitelist,[]},
 {affiliations,[{{"test1","54.69.16.10",[]},{owner,[]}}]}]
```

I would extract first level with proplists:

```
2> Affiliations =  proplists:get_value(affiliations,Listt).
[{{"test1","54.69.16.10",[]},{owner,[]}}]
```

`lists:map/2` and pattern matching can help you transform the list with just the first part of the structure:

```
3> Users = lists:map(fun({User, Role}) -> User end, Affiliations).
[{"test1","54.69.16.10",[]}]
```

If you want to extract even further, you can do:

```
4> lists:map(fun({Username, Server, _}) -> Username end, User). 
["test1"]
```

or you can even do step 3 and 4 at once and get a list of users:

```
5> lists:map(fun({{User, Server, _}, Role}) -> User end, Affiliations).       
["test1"]
```